# module_end extended event enough for stored procedure logging?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, extended-events

Using extended events I plan to capture stored procedure executions particular the time of execution, duration and who executed it.

Is the `module_end` event enough to capture this data? In a test session I have created I don't see what more the `module_start` event would provide though would a `module_end` event occur if a stored procedure execution is terminated?

Comment: Since you have an XE session running (that you didn't show us a definition for), why don't you just try killing a stored procedure while it's running to see what happens?

Comment: As @sp_BlitzErik noted, you are in a perfect position to test this.

Comment: Yes if I could currently access the instance of SQL server

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question - when a stored procedure execution is aborted then this is logged as an event, in which case I don't see the need to capture both `module_start` and `module_end` events for my purpose.